# Rails seed file not creating record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am seeding a database for a rails project and one of my records is not being created. I can create it using the same exact syntax in rails console, but it just doesn't work in the seed file. Here is the code from the seed file:

```
admin = Admin.find_by_email('example@example.com')
if !admin
admin = Admin.create(:email => 'example@example.com', :password => 'password',              :password_confirmation => 'password', :first_name =>
 'example', :last_name => 'admin')
end

if !Project.find_by_name('Templates')
  Project.create(:name => 'Templates', :admin => admin)
  if Project.find_by_name("Templates")
     puts "Project Found"
  else
    puts "Project not Found"
  end  
end
```

When I run 'rake db:seed' it always says "Project not Found". If I run the same create statement in the rails console, it gives me back the created Project object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it could be because you are trying to create a record which is not valid. I'm used to use the banged method (`save!` / `create!`) in seeds file to prevent this kind of problems.

Comment: Thanks so much, that worked. It was silently failing with the non-banged create method, and with the create! method it actually told me what went wrong.

Answer (score 2):

First guess, should you be referencing the admin id when you create a project? Is the column in the project table actually 'admin_id'?

```
Project.create(:name => 'Templates', :admin_id => admin.id)
```

Second thing I'd try is putting a puts after the bit where you create the admin to make sure that bit worked. You've got nothing to say wherther that bit worked before the project bit then failed.

Edit 1:

Try doing something like this on the bottom half of your seeds file and it should output the error if the step didn't work:

```
project = Project.find_or_initialize_by_name_and_admin('Templates', admin)
puts project.errors if project.nil?
```

Comment: I added a check for the admin and got a success from that. I also changed the :admin => admin to :admin_id => admin.id but still got nothing. I initially was doing it that way but though maybe I was supposed to pass in the whole admin object to create the association.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm pretty new to rails and didn't know about the errors property. It will definitely come in handy down the road, I'm sure.

Comment: No problem. the ! methods are fine but they do bypass any validation in your models so use carefully. There may be a good reason that something fails....